# Remove Space in MS Word above footer

Tags: ms-word, ms-office

I am struggling a lot to remove the space I have marked into the images(it is the space before the footer). It's a very small problem but it is creating a lot of pain for me.

I am not able to use that space and it is a wastage of my precious page.

I tried many ways- Aligning the footer. used the left ruler to change the spacing, also use the paragraph alignment but not successful. So, now I am here to ask for a solution.

Please let me know if anyone has the perfect solution.

Word version : Microsoft 365 app for entriprise[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not a programming question and you should post questions like this on either MS-Answers or SuperUser ... however, see my answer below.

Comment: no solution is working at all so I thought. Programming minds will be good to make it fix for me. sorry but your solution below is not working.

Answer (score 1):

*Normal document standards call for a visual break between the body and the footer.*

### Look into the space-before formatting of your footer style.

1. Go into the footer (Edit Footer)
2. Click in the footer's first line
3. Right-click and pick Paragraph
4. Adjust the Space-before formatting for the paragraph
5. When you have the spacing you want, find the Footer style and modify it - update to current formatting.

Comment: please elaborate this ,,, not getting what to do

Comment: I've amended my answer to provide steps.

Answer (score 1):

Adjust it with a Custom Margin setting, which is located on the Layout tab > Margins menu. Take the bottom margin down to about 0.5 inches or 1.27 cm.